# Burninate the [automation] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just encountered a suggested edit which added the [automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automation) tag to a C#/Selenium question.

This left me wondering: What is the intent of that tag?

I started by searching for a definition of "automation". [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automation):

> **Automation**, or **Labor-saving technology** is the technology by which a process or procedure is performed with minimal human assistance.

IMHO, this is a quite broad definition, which, even when restricted to programming, covers lots of possible applications. This view is supported by the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/automation/info), which also points to several sub tags:

- [build-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build-automation): 1781 questions
- [ole-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ole-automation): 86 questions
- [automated-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automated-tests): 10125 questions
- [ui-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-automation): 2889 questions

Checking out the [automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automation) tag shows 17087 questions, with a wide range of topics, for example:

- [Passing an argument to a PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592531/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-powershell-script)
- [`watch` command in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574089/osx-bash-watch-command)
- [Typing keys in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-using-python-and-selenium)
- [Formatting numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113200/php-number-decimal-point-visible-only-if-needed)
- [Creating file shortcuts with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023379/creating-a-file-shortcut-lnk)
- [Auto-deleting old rows with a stored procedure in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507258/stored-procedure-that-automatically-delete-rows-older-than-7-days-in-mysql)
- [Converting .doc files to .pdf files using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)

There are exactly [100 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1256696/questions-with-automation-as-only-tag) which have [automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automation) as their only tag. Some of those are off-topic/too broad, and for others there are better tags.

---

I don't think that the general [automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automation) tag adds much value:
Automation is merely a concept, with a broad range of possible applications, as the above question links show. I could argue for all of those questions, why the notion "automation" would fit there (so the tag isn't actually wrong). However, I could also argue for *most other* programming questions, why those are about "automation" in one way or another.

To solve this, I propose to

- use the more specific sub tags wherever appropriate,
- and get rid or at least discourage the use of the general [automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automation) tag.

Comment: You may want to consider reading the tag wiki for [burninate-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info), which goes into the rules around such requests, and has links to helpful resources, including a link to the SOCVR chat room, where people experienced in these things can help guide you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with SOCVR, I didn't know it is on-topic there. I read the tag wiki (and the process), but wasn't sure about some points.

Comment: Discourage yes. Get rid of completely, probably too much effort. It looks like a meta-tag and very superfluous but I am not sure if it is causing active harm.

Comment: @Dharman questions with only this tag don't get properly closed.

Comment: @Braiam True, but questions with other tags like Python or PHP don't get properly closed either. I don't think the problem is with the tag but the number of questions that need to be closed.

Comment: @Dharman it's a problem of discoverability, I agree, but at least with this tag the solution is in our hands.

Comment: There's also the branch of industrial automation (factory lines), which is often referred to as just "automation". There's various branch-specific software subjects below that one such as PLC programming.

Comment: To add to the arguments: Automation is the main purpose of programming, which in turn is the topic of this site. (See, e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming): “The purpose of programming is to find a sequence of instructions that will **automate** the performance of a task […] on a computer, […].” Of course, there are sometimes cases, where the only interface you have for something is a programming language and you need to use it without the intent to automate something, but those are the exception. You might as well have a tag [programming].

Comment: I just saw the [automation] tag and was confused.  How is every post on SO not related to automation?  Isn't it all about writing code so that humans don't need to do the tedium?  Since it applies to everything, the tag is meaningless.